# python regex: escape illegal characters only if it's not escaped already

Tags: python, json, regex

Right now I'm taking in files as string and formatting them into json. The file contains \r, \n characters that I want to escape, but there are json objects in the files which already has those illegal characters escaped, like \\r and \\n. So right now I want to replace \r \n characters with \\r \\n only if it's not preceded by one \

I have tried this below.. but I'm not sure why it doesn't work

```
re.sub(r'[^\][\n]', r'\\\\n', s)
```

any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this using RegEx:

```
import re                                    

data = 'Hello\r\nWorld\\r\\n'                
print(data)                                  

print('-'*20)                                

data = re.sub(r'([^\\])\r', '\\1\\\\r', data)
data = re.sub(r'([^\\])\n', '\\1\\\\n', data)
print(data)
```

**Outputs:**

```
Hello               
World\r\n           
--------------------
Hello\r\nWorld\r\n
```

Or, a slightly different approach would be to do it like this:

```
data = 'Hello\r\nWorld\\r\\n'                          
print(data)                                            

print('-'*20)                                          

data = data.replace('\r', '\\r')
data = data.replace('\n', '\\n')
print(data)
```

**Outputs:**

```
Hello               
World\r\n           
--------------------
Hello\r\nWorld\r\n
```

Comment: what does the second replace in each do? It seems to me that once we've replaced all the <CR> characters, there won't be any sequences of `\\\r` == `<backslash><CR>` left

Comment: the initial answer worked fine! Thanks! I will try the regex version

Comment: from my test with your string, the double replace isn't neccessary, see http://pastebin.com/v9DTn0hp . Its because your first replace, which affects only ASCII 13 carriage returns doesn't affect anything that is a literal backslash (ASCII 92) followed by a literal r (ASCII 114)

Comment: @turbulencetoo You're right, I'd overlooked that. I'll make an edit. Thanks